# Extract Sample Data Object from database for testing

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing

I am working on my TDD skills and I am using entity framework to link my business objects to my data. I have some large models with 60 or so properties. During debug I can mouse over the object and see the populated data.

Q: Is there a utility that can use to extract that class with the data into static code that I can use for testing?

*Pseudo example:*

```
public class person{
    public string First {get;set;}
    public string Last {get;set;}
    public Address Address {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

...

```
public DbSet<Person> People {get;set;}
```

... Extracted result would be

```
var p = new Person { First="Pete", Last="Niemann", 
                     Address = new Address { 
                         Street = "123 Main", 
                         City="Anytown", 
                         State="CA", 
                         Zip="12345" 
                         }
                   };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need a code generator for this. another option is to persist the model as xml via XmlSerializer. you can then modify your xml for your tests and load it other way around.